Unable to access Kubernetes service through Ingress from Internet on GCP(VMs) with nginx-ingress-controller and MetalLB
I’ve set up a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) using kubeadm with the following configuration:
Cluster Setup
3 Virtual Machines (VMs) on GCP
1 Master Node and 2 Worker Nodes
Installed nginx-ingress-controller and MetalLB on the Master Node
Issue
I deployed an application and exposed it as a ClusterIP service, then created an Ingress resource for this service. The Ingress shows the IP assigned by nginx-ingress-controller, but I cannot access the service through this IP from the public internet.
Steps Taken
Verified the configurations for nginx-ingress-controller and MetalLB
Confirmed that MetalLB assigned the correct external IP
Checked GCP firewall rules to allow external access to relevant ports
